# What is the syslog() facility if none is net using openlog()

Tags: c, unix, freebsd, syslog

I am trying to use `syslog()` and reading through the man pages tells me that in `openlog()`, "The facility argument establishes a default to be used if none is specified in subsequent calls to `syslog()`"

So from what I understand, the way to do it is : 1. Call `openlog` to set the facility 2. Call `syslog()` to log. 3. Call `closelog()`.

But what if I do not call openlog() before calling syslog()? What is the facility then? What is meant by "establishes a default to be used if none is specified". Where can one be specified, if not `openlog()`?

Answer (score 1):

Aah I think I got it. I think what it means is that for

syslog(int priority, const char *message, ...);

here priority can be multiple flags, as given in the freebsd man page example :

syslog(LOG_INFO|LOG_LOCAL2, "foobar error: %m");

Here the facility is LOG_LOCAL2 and priority is LOG_INFO. So the facility mentioned in openlog() will take effect if none is provided in a call to syslog() as above.